# search string with html tags

Tags: php, html, strpos

I have html content in PHP variable and I want to search for particular string with it's tags.

suppose my variable is

```
$var = "<html>Hi.. <strong>how</strong>are <u>you?</u></html>
```

Now I want to search for how in `$var` then it should return me with it's tag so I should get **how**

how this can be done using PHP?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: for what you search for and what is your desired output? Please clear it.

Comment: You want to use strip_tags()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using regex:

```
$search = 'how';
$var = "<html>Hi.. <strong>how</strong>are <u>you?</u></html>";
preg_match_all('/<[^>]+>'.$search.'<\/[^>]+>/',$var,$matches);
$found = $matches[0][0];
echo $found;
```

Output:

**how**

To get all `how` strings, those with and without tags, change your regex to this (add `OR` `|` operator:

```
preg_match_all('/<[^>]+>'.$search.'<\/[^>]+>|\b'.$search.'\b/',$var,$matches);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! it's perfect what I wanted

Comment: suppose my $var = "<html>how .. <strong>how</strong>are <u>you?</u></html>"; then is it possible to get both the how 
1. how
2. <strong>how</strong>

Comment: sure, all the matches will be in `$matches[0]` array with corresponding key.

Comment: No I mean to say if 'how' is not surrounded by any tag then will it search?

Comment: Actually I want both 'how' from $var so one 'how' is simple how and another should be with tags. the tags part is provided by you. can you write regex that will return both the 'how'?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to have the element containing your value? You could go for an xpath approach:

```
<?php
$var = "<html>Hi.. <strong>how</strong>are <u>you?</u></html>";
$xml = simplexml_load_string($var);
$elements = $xml->xpath("//*[. = 'how']");
# looking for any value in the tree where the text equals 'how'
# giving back an array of found matches
print_r($elements);
?>
```

See an [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/1POxx6) demo here.

Comment: it's only giving me how. not the tags besides it

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about your question??

If you want to know your searching string is in the $var or not then please try this.

```
<?php
$var = "<html>Hi.. <strong>how</strong>are <u>you?</u></html>";
$findme = "how";
$pos = strpos($var, $findme);
if($pos === false)
  echo $findme.", Not found.";
else
  echo $findme.", The string found";
?>
```

Comment: it will only search for how not the tags besides it

Comment: Yes, if you want to retrieve the search string with surrounding tags then you have to use regular expression for better output as easy way.

you got the answer, so go ahead.

Comment: yes that answer helped me. Thanks for your answer though